# Canonicalise lists of JSONs in different order into the same hash

Tags: json, hash, canonicalization

Given two different JSONs

```
first = {"number": 1, "color": blue}
```

and

```
second = {"number": 2, "color": red}
```

How could I canonicalise the following to have the same hash?

```
{"list": [first, second]}
{"list": [second, first]}
```

I have tried using this [RFC 8785](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8785) compliant [library](https://github.com/cyberphone/json-canonicalization/tree/master/python3) but it doesn't sort the lists so the hash would end up different.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-canonicalize

Comment: "JSON Array data is also subject to canonicalization, but element order remains untouched" - so it'd still give a different hash, is there a standardised way to sort?